# Finding files on the classpath by an inclusion/exclusion pattern

Tags: java, classpath

Is there a way to scan the classpath for certain patterns of resources?
I would like to be able to find resources by inclusion/exclusion parameters.

I would prefer not to use Spring.

For example, I would like to find all resource files that match: `META-INF/properties/*.properties`.

Looking forward to your ideas and comments! :)

Comment: You'll have to re-write your own.  Why the Spring objection?

Comment: @duffymo: Just a restriction that ties my hands for a lot of things, but a requirement for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem down:

1. Parser to accept and parse paths, interpreting wild cards.  Can be recursive if you use the ** notation that Ant uses.
2. Way to look through all the paths and look for the files called for and return a data structure with paths or Files.

Ant does it.  Could you reuse the JARs that it uses?  That would give you the capability without Spring.

Comment: Ant has `DirectoryScanner. I think Plexus also has it's own implementation. I am not sure if you could do it with apache commons-io which would be best for me. I was thinking of this and hooking it up with TrueZip. Any better ideas would be highly appreciated!